# Only Output BitLocker ID and Key with manage-bde

Tags: windows, batch, bitlocker

I am working on a batch script to run as a scheduled task on some machines tied to a network to automatically run and backup the BitLocker keys to a secure location. I can get the keys backed up just fine into some text files, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way to grab the information. Currently logs look like this:

```
Host: SFXXXXXXXX
User: Doe, John
Timestamp: 08\26\2022 @ 16:26

BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: [Windows]
All Key Protectors

    TPM:
      ID: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
      PCR Validation Profile:
        0, 2, 4, 11

    Numerical Password:
      ID: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
      Password:
        XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I would rather do away with the TPM details since they do not pertain to my needs. Is there a switch or argument I can use to only get the key and associated device ID? Something that would look more like this:

```
Host: SFXXXXXXXX
User: Doe, John
Timestamp: 08\26\2022 @ 16:26

Volume C: [Windows]

Numerical Password:
ID: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
Password:
XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The formatting doesn't have to match what I have in mind exactly, I just want less fluff in the files.

Comment: Do you have Active Directory? Just let the machines back up their recovery keys to Active Directory.

Comment: I do @user1686, however I am still being tasked with making separate file backups as I offered to do so.

Comment: If you are making separate backup files - would it be easier for you to just [query AD for the keys?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2251939-pull-bitlocker-keys-from-active-directory-via-powershell)

Comment: The issue is that some keys are not in AD. I don't know why but the primary purpose of this is to get keys to begin with @Narzard. I know there are better ways of doing this, but this is how I have been tasked with doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manage-bde -protectors -get c: -t RecoveryPassword
```

This will display only the recovery password.